# The file was set up right but eof() and peek() return wrong value from new stream unexpectedly

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream

I want to generate a random array.

```
void Random_nums(int n, string fileName) {

    ofstream fsave(fileName);
    int ranArray[n];

    srand( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        ranArray[i]=rand()%2001 - 1000;
        fsave << ranArray[i] << '\n'; //save them into ranArray
    }

    fsave.close();
}
```

And I want to save them into a separate file.

After that I want to read the data I just saved and implement them in a new function.

```
void FunctionWantToUse(string inputFile, string outputFile) {

    //reading data
    ifstream fin(inputFile);
    cout << fin.is_open();//which is 1

    //how many numbers are there in this file
    int n = 0;
    n = distance(istream_iterator<int>(fin), istream_iterator<int>());

    //restore the array
    int array[n];

    //test
    cout << fin.peek() << ' ' << EOF;//they are both -1!

    //another test
    cout << fin.peek() << '\n'; //which return -1
    cout << fin.eof() << '\n'; //which return 1

    //since peek() and EOF both return -1, I can't get into this loop. 
    while (fin.peek() != EOF) {
        if ((fin >> array[i]).good()) {
            cout << array[i];
        }
    }
```

Completely have no idea why the value of fin.peek() and fin.eof() change to -1 and 1 respectively.

And the console told me this as I run these two functions.

```
-1 -1-1
1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I also give some other tests, such as, place fsave.eof() in the loop when I generate random number, and it prints out all 0s.

Could someone please tell me what's going on here? I completely have no clue right now.

Comment: `istream::eof()` returns a `bool`.  When printed a `bool` only has values `0` or `1`.   `EOF` is a macro from C that typically expands to an `int` literal, and will probably have a value that is outside the range of normal characters - so cannot be `0` or `1`.    Therefore `EOF` and `fin.eof()` cannot compare equal.       `fin.peek()` (for a stock standard stream) returns `std::char_traits(char>::eof()`.     Short solution:  avoid testing status of C++ streams using C macros (like `EOF`).

Answer (score 3):

With `std::distance(istream_iterator<int>(fin), istream_iterator<int>())` you walk through the file until it fails to read and `int`. That an happen either because there is some input which cannot be parsed as `int` (after skipping leading whitespace) or end of file is reached. In any case, when the call to `distance()` returns the stream will have `std::ios_base::failbit` set and if the error is due to end of file being reach also `std::ios_base::failbit`.

The obvious fix is to *not* determine the distance and instead to read the integers directly into a suitable representation. For example:

```
std::vector<int> array{std::istream_iterator<int>(fin),
                       std::istream_iterator<int>()};
```

If you really want to use loop instead, you should test for the stream to be not in fail state **after** reading from the stream, e.g.:

```
for (int tmp; fin >> tmp; ) {
    // use tmp
}
```

When you really feel you need to determine the number of elements first, you'll need to

1. `clear()` the stream state after it got `std::ios_base::failbit` set. Without that most stream operations will simply be ignored.
2. `seekg()` back to the start of the stream.

Note, however, that resizing a `std::vector<int>` a few times will almost certainly be more effective than reading through a file and parsing its contents twice.

BTW, your use of array has two problems:

1. Variable sized arrays are **not** part of standard C++ although some compilers do support them as an extension.
2. If the file is of a reasonable size you'll get a stack overflow.

You are much better off using `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just fixed it.!